# diagonal matrix in Latex

Tags: matrices

Does anybody know how I can get these symbols for a diagonal matrix in Latex?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure there must be a better way, but you can combine a rotated `rule` with the brackets and a few `hspace`s and get kind of close. Note this won't scale vertically so don't try to put fractions (or something else tall) between the brackets. The expression with normal brackets is shown as well for comparison.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newcommand\diagmatrix[1]{[\hspace{-1.6pt}\raisebox{7pt}{\rotatebox{-30}{\rule{1mm}{.15mm}}}\hspace{-1pt}#1\hspace{-1pt}\raisebox{-1pt}{\rotatebox{-30}{\rule{1mm}{.15mm}}}\hspace{-1.6pt}]}
\begin{document}
\[\diagmatrix{m_r}^{-1}\diagmatrix{k_r}\]
\[[m_r]^{-1}[k_r]\]
\end{document}
```

[image]